# Android Transition framework and data from network

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I have been trying to use the android transition framework but am running into some issues.
I have an ImageView which moves from the center of the screen to the top left. Everything works fine but the image which is loaded from the server disappears from the imageview as soon as the new scene enters. I understand that it is the view which is as such transitioning, and the content gets lost. But how do i handle this issue.The code is as below:-

```
<!-scene1.xml-->
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="215dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/theimage"
    />
 </RelativeLayout>

<!--scene2.xml-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="215dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/theimage"
    />
 </RelativeLayout>

<!--theFragment-->
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View theViewGroup=inflater.inflate(R.layout.scene1, container, false);
    //both scene1 and scene 2 contain an imageview
    //the imageview of scene1 is populated by an image downloaded by picasso

    RelativeLayout thecont= (RelativeLayout) movieDetailView.findViewById(R.id.moviedesccontainer);

    mScene=Scene.getSceneForLayout(thecont,R.layout.scene2,getActivity());
    someButton.onClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(){
            //when scene2 comes is the imageview has moved to the desired place but there is no image in there.How do we get the image which we downloaded earlier
           TransitionManager.go(mScene);
          };
    });
    return movieDetailView;
}
```

Comment: You need to populate R.id.theimage ImageViews of both scene1 *and* scene2 with the downloaded picasso image.